# Errors when installing fbctf

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to `install Facebook Capture` the flag.  I get the errors show in screenshot.

The Server is the recommended **Ubuntu 14.4.  Server 64bit.**

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some kind of locale issue. Maybe you can check [here](https://github.com/facebook/fbctf/issues/28):

"Do you have your locale settings configured correctly? The vendor folder won't get created properly if you don't. I recommend following the instructions on this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue"

Answer (score 0):

The install instructions have been updated and is working as expected now.